# Is this peer to peer? UDP Java chat service

Tags: java, udp, p2p

I am currently coding a Peer to Peer UDP Chat Service.
I have two Threads for each Client, one that receives and one that sends the messages, such that both can be done simultaneously. I was struggling really hard on how I could "find out" what ports the other Clients would be connected to, so I decided to create a "Broadcast" Class (Thread), where the Clients will send a message to once they are created. The Broadcast stores each unique InetAddress + Port in a HashMap, and then sends the received message to every Client in the HashMap.

So my Question would be: Is this even considered P2P? Technically they do not send the message to each other directly. I am really struggling to find a way to implement other Ideas I had, such as only using the Broadcast Class to create this HashMap with Client Information, then transferring this HashMap to each Client, so that they could now send directly to every Peer. But then I run into other questions such as: How would my Receiving Thread communicated this HashMap to the Sending Thread?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, this is not p2p.

Divide your program to two steps: first the client, on it's main thread, will get the connection details form the broadcast server, and only then it will spin up the threads for listening/posting. This is the common pattern for such programs.

If you don't know the port ahead of time (because you want to use the random port assigned by the OS) you have two options:

1. Have the "receiving thread" post to the broadcast server the port it's listening on, and the "sending thread" will pull from the broadcast server to which ip/port it needs to send. The fact that a thread is a "receiving thread" states its role, not that it is not allowed to send requests.
2. You can have an object that is accessed by both threads (passed to them on initialization) to pass the information. This object must be thread safe.

In my opinion option 1 is cleaner. It's simple and more SOLID.

Comment: Thank you. I managed to do it differently. My Broadcast class became a "Register" that every Client once they are created, will send a Packet to. Since the Chat should not start until an X amount of Clients are registered, Broadcast will store each unique InetSocketAddress in an ArrayList. Once X unique Clients have registered, the Register will send the Unique InetSocketAddresses to everyone, so that now each Client has information about the Other Clients.